# One comment html form for many posts in single page (DRY advice)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dry, one-to-many

I am showing multiple posts in one page and want to add comments through a modal box. Yet I do not want to repeat the comment form for every post record.

For the time being, I added "id" parameter to "comment" link inside post box, plus a hidden field inside form "comment_post_id" with an empty value, and manipulating it via jQuery as follows:

```
$('.comment').click(function() {
    var id;
    id = $(this).attr("id");

    $('#comment_post_id').attr('value', '');
    $('#comment_post_id').attr('value', id);
});
```

is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: This looks like jQuery/javascript code to me. Why have you tagged it with rails tags?

Comment: Ok. added it. But then again I am looking for an answer from Rails side mostly.

Comment: Can we have rails-best-practices tag please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a remote link_to for each post which does an ajax request to get the comments form for the post. That way you'd have something that would degrade gracefully if javascript was turned off (it'd just load the comments form using a normal request).

The downside is that you'll have an extra HTTP request to load the comments form.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal way. I do this way myself several times. I think there is no other chance to do it.